# Error in SQL Server CE query parse

Tags: c#, parsing, sql-server-ce

So, I want to insert this query into the database file:

```
UPDATE contas 
SET nome = @nome, endereço = @endereco, serv_envio = @envio, 
    serv_recep = @recep, pass = @pass, user = @user, 
    tipo = @tipo, Seguro = @seguro 
WHERE id = @id
```

However, every time I try to put it, I get this error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 101, Token in error = user]

However, after an hour trying to figure out was could be wrong, I still can't find the error.

Also here's the database:

Table: `Contas`

Columns:

- ID (Primary Integer Auto-Increase)
- Nome (text)
- Endereço (text)
- Serv_Envio (text)
- Serv_Recep (text)
- User (text)
- Pass (text)
- Tipo (Foreign Integer)
- Defeito (Boolean)
- Seguro (Boolean)

And here is the parametrization (C#):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", tb_nome.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", tb_mail.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@envio", tb_envio.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recep", tb_recep.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", tb_pass.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", tb_user.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", cb_tipo.SelectedIndex + 1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idconta);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seguro", seguro);
```

So, any help?

Thanks in advance.

João Borrego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word. Try:

```
UPDATE contas SET nome=@nome, endereço=@endereco, serv_envio=@envio, 
  serv_recep=@recep, pass=@pass, [user]=@user, tipo=@tipo, Seguro=@seguro 
WHERE id=@id;
```

Or rename the column.

Comment: I used the brackets. Thanks it worked! Now, I will avoid using that word in the future :P